# c# PagedList Async

Tags: c#, winforms, pagination

I have a problem with pagedlist.

I want to change selected columns but not working. So I want to make this:

```
return db.stock_products.select(x=> new {x.id,x.title,x.etc}).AsExpandable().Where(classFilter).OrderByDescending(x => x.id).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
```

Code:

```
 public async Task<IPagedList<DAL.stock_products>> GetPagedListAsync(int pageNumber = 1, int pageSize = 23)
        {
            try
            {
                return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    if (isFiltered == false)
                    {
                        return db.stock_products.Where(x=>x.quantity>0).OrderByDescending(x => x.id).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
                    }

                    isFiltered = false;

                    return db.stock_products.AsExpandable().Where(classFilter).OrderByDescending(x => x.id).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);

                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Stop", "Hata", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
                Application.Exit();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code;

```
return db.stock_products.Select(x=> new DAL.stock_products {id=x.id,title=x.title,etc=x.etc}).AsExpandable().Where(classFilter).OrderByDescending(x => x.id).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
```